# Hide Stock Qty/Availability for Specific Attribute Set

Tags: php, jquery, magento, magento-1.9

I have a bit of an odd situation that I am trying to fix.   **Magento v1.9.2.4**

- I have only 2 different attribute sets. A and B.
- I want to display the stock quantity/availability for set B, but not
  set A.

To make things a bit more complex, I have 14 Customer Groups, I only want 6 of those groups to ever see any quantities/availability.

Here's what I have done so far to arrange this:

```
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
      $groupId = $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
      $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
      if ('custgroup_1' == $group->getCode()){ 
        $qty = (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
        echo 'Quantity Available: ' . $qty;
    }
}
```

The above snippet is repeated 5 times with the [if ('custgroup_1' ...] changed to accommodate the group I need this to show up for.  That part is working just fine.

I only need to specify somehow that I only want the availability to show up for the attribute set B.  Then Regardless of the customer group never show the qty/availability for attribute set A.

I have tried playing with the inventory options on the product page. (disabled stock management = qty still shows | enabled stock management, set qty to 0 and my custom options disappear | ect.) Nothing within the magento backend seems to work.

I'm a newbie to this whole Magento/Dev thing.  So I apologize if this is considered a silly question.

Thank you for any/all help!

Answer (score 0):

So, Immediately after posting this I realized I was thinking about the problem all wrong.

Because any item that isn't in attribute set B isn't having stock managed, I was able to write a condition that enables output only for products that have an inventory level greater than 0.

Here is the code for anyone who might happen to need to show a quantity for products based on a customer group, and hide availability for any item that has inventory management set to no, but is set to "In Stock".

```
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
      $groupId = $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
      $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
      if ('custgroup_1' == $group->getCode()){
         $__manStock = $_product->getStockItem()->getManageStock();
         $__invAmt = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
 if ($__manStock > 0)
        echo $this->__("Available Qty:  $__invAmt");
    }
}
```